# Is it odd that there is only one sentence about the death of David?

Tags: history, death, david, time, life

I read in 2nd Samuel from the time that David was anointed with oil to the beginning of Judges to Davids death and burial. Davids life is described in much detail, great detail. Both good and bad are described and a full accurate picture is formed of David, his time and run-ins with Saul, his Kingship and many battles and wars that brought about. His relationships and friendships, his wives and children. His many travels and explorations. Of course, his sins and wrong choices. His blessing and curses, David and his own Book of Deuteronomy, lol. But in all this great detail of his life only one sentence about being laid to rest with his fathers in the City of David. I find that extremely odd. Thus far, I can only chalk that up to, it doesn't matter the final resting spot; as far as a tomb or the process of the dead. It matters what was done in life. It matters what was done in and with the time allotted, given to us, by the Father.

I just found it really odd that chapter after chapter you read about the life and all the good and bad of David, then all of a sudden 1 sentence and that is a wrap, on to Solomon. But I guess that is sort of what life is really like any way. Out with one, on to the next one. Sad to say, so do something in Life that will last, the Light will last. Do something in the Light, ya, thats it...God Loves You...Thank you for your time

Comment: What exactly is your question? This is a question-and-answer site, rather than a more general discussion site.

Comment: Welcome to Christianity SE and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and [how it is different than others](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1809/50259).

Answer (score 3):

2 Samuel 23 begins with David's last words :

> The Spirit of the LORD spake by me, and his word was in my tongue.3The God of Israel said, the Rock of Israel spake to me, He that ruleth over men must be just, ruling in the fear of God.4And he shall be as the light of the morning, when the sun riseth, even a morning without clouds; as the tender grass springing out of the earth by clear shining after rain.5Although my house be not so with God; yet he hath made with me an everlasting covenant, ordered in all things, and sure: for this is all my salvation, and all my desire, although he make it not to grow.6But the sons of Belial shall be all of them as thorns thrust away, because they cannot be taken with hands:7But the man that shall touch them must be fenced with iron and the staff of a spear; and they shall be utterly burned with fire in the same place.

There follows an account of David's mighty men. (The rest of 23.)

Then there follows an account of the incident of the numbering of the people and its consequences and its resolution (Chapter 24)

Then there is an account of David's last days and the involvement of Nathan in ensuring Solomon's enthronement. (1 Kings 1)

Then there follows the account of David's death. (1 Kings 2:1-11)

---

This is a very extensive narrative of David's last days and decease, covering three and some chapters, and including necessary matters of his life requiring explanations and final, conclusory documentation.

The entirety could be considered as David's 'Last Will and Testament', or as 'legacy', in the modern meaning of that word.

It is certainly not 'one sentence'.